# Create operator / function for custom type in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, database-indexes, custom-type

I have the following custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE param_range AS (  
    param smallint,
    range int4range
);
```

The following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test4
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    geo point,
    ext param_range[]
)
```

The following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test4_geo ON test4 USING GIST ((geo));
CREATE INDEX ix_test4_ext on test4 USING GIN (ext);
```

The GIN index requires an operator / function for the custom type. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GIN index doesn't just require a custom operator.  It requires a whole family of operators.  Basically you need to:

1. Consult the documentation regarding GIN opclasses.
2. Write a set of IMMUTABLE functions to handle those.
3. Write a set of operators based on those functions.
4. Tie those together in a custom operator class.

This isn't a simple, small amount of work.  It requires a fair bit of though (what does "overlap" mean in the context of your type?" and so you need to expect to spend a fair bit of time in the design phase.

Basically if you want GIST/GIN support you are designing a custom type not just for storage but for operational purposes.  This is a project.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This dawned on me after digging deep into online documentation, and when no one answered.

Comment: would you please expand a bit on point number 4? I have asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34407438/1319179